# Cannot get response 200 with spring boot

Tags: web-services, spring-boot, model-view-controller, http-status-code-404

Hi i am testing my controllers methods with chrome's reslet client and i have an error 404, after checking everything in my project i built a new one and created just one service and one controller and still all i get is error 404.
any ideas?

---

this is the url im calling: 
     http://localhost:8080/rest/api/encryptor/checkAutorization

that is my  PomXML with al the dependencys :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.serverside</groupId>
<artifactId>app</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>app</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

this is the Controller:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import Services.GeneralResponse;
import Services.TokenEncryptor;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("rest/api/encryptor")
public class EncryptionController {

@Autowired
private TokenEncryptor tokenEncryptor;


@GetMapping("/checkAutorization")
public GeneralResponse checkAutorization() throws Throwable {
    try {
//          byte[] byteToken = token.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        return new GeneralResponse(tokenEncryptor.encryptToken(new byte[] 
{}));
    } catch (Exception AccessDeniedException) {
        return new GeneralResponse(AccessDeniedException);
    }
}


}
```

Main method:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
public class AppApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(AppApplication.class, args);
}

}
```

General Response Class:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class GeneralResponse {
private Object error;
private Object result;

public GeneralResponse() {
}

public GeneralResponse(Object result) {
    this.result = result;
}

public GeneralResponse(Exception e) {
    this.result = null;
    this.error = e;

    StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = e.getStackTrace();
    System.out.println("The exception occured in method " + stackTrace[0].getMethodName());
    System.out.println("The class name is " + stackTrace[0].getClassName());
    System.out.println("at line number: " + stackTrace[0].getLineNumber());
    System.out.println(e.toString() + " \n" + "error cause: " + e.getCause() + "\n" + "at: " + formatTime(System.currentTimeMillis()));
}

public Object getError() {
    return error;
}

public void setError(Object error) {
    this.error = error;
}

public Object getResult() {
    return result;
}

public void setResult(Object result) {
    this.result = result;
}

private String formatTime(Long currentTime) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm");
    Date resultdate = new Date(currentTime);
    return (sdf.format(resultdate));
}
```

}

Console startup log :

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.1.RELEASE)

2018-12-17 13:40:20.763  INFO 21872 --- [  restartedMain] com.serverside.app.AppApplication        : Starting AppApplication on LAPTOP-0GNLE6KN with PID 21872 (C:\Users\omert\eclipse-workspace\app\target\classes started by omert in C:\Users\omert\eclipse-workspace\app)
2018-12-17 13:40:20.766  INFO 21872 --- [  restartedMain] com.serverside.app.AppApplication        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-12-17 13:40:20.814  INFO 21872 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2018-12-17 13:40:20.815  INFO 21872 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2018-12-17 13:40:21.546  INFO 21872 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2018-12-17 13:40:21.569  INFO 21872 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 15ms. Found 0 repository interfaces.
2018-12-17 13:40:21.946  INFO 21872 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$365e8361] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-12-17 13:40:22.515  INFO 21872 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-12-17 13:40:22.541  INFO 21872 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-12-17 13:40:22.542  INFO 21872 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.13
2018-12-17 13:40:22.554  INFO 21872 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_191/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_191/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_191/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\omert\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\omert\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe;;C:\WINDOWS\system32;;.]
2018-12-17 13:40:22.697  INFO 21872 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-12-17 13:40:22.697  INFO 21872 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1882 ms
2018-12-17 13:40:22.915  INFO 21872 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2018-12-17 13:40:23.063  INFO 21872 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2018-12-17 13:40:23.109  INFO 21872 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2018-12-17 13:40:23.178  INFO 21872 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.7.Final}
2018-12-17 13:40:23.181  INFO 21872 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2018-12-17 13:40:23.338  INFO 21872 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
2018-12-17 13:40:23.482  INFO 21872 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2018-12-17 13:40:23.713  INFO 21872 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.t.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl  : HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@77c8a0a2'
2018-12-17 13:40:23.716  INFO 21872 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-12-17 13:40:23.731  INFO 21872 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2018-12-17 13:40:23.983  INFO 21872 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2018-12-17 13:40:24.038  WARN 21872 --- [  restartedMain] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2018-12-17 13:40:24.325  INFO 21872 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2018-12-17 13:40:24.329  INFO 21872 --- [  restartedMain] com.serverside.app.AppApplication        : Started AppApplication in 3.869 seconds (JVM running for 4.415)
```

Comment: What URL are you calling?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/rest/api/encryptor/checkAutorization

Comment: Have you had a look at the output when you start the app? Do you see this URL?

Comment: cannot see it in the console either in chrome

Comment: can you post the startup log?

Comment: yes just a minute

Comment: try removing @Configuration on your application class

Comment: removed it , didnt work

Comment: I created a github repo with your code and this is working. Check it out https://github.com/simasch/53812861

Answer (score 0):

I am getting 200 response code

POM : http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    org.gjp.springboot
    test
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    jar
    test
    Test Spring Boot Web Application
    
        org.springframework.boot
        spring-boot-starter-parent
        2.0.0.RELEASE

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
```

@Service
public class TokenEncryptor {